# Is the image of the linear operator $(Mf)(x):=m(x)f(x)$ closed in $L^2$? Where $m(x) = x$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $0$ else.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $M:L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ be the linear, bounded operator given by:
$(Mf)(x) = m(x)\cdot f(x)$ where $m(x) = \begin{cases} 
x& \text{for}\: x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}],\\
0& \text{else}.
\end{cases}$

Does $M$ have closed range ?

My ideas:
I tried to take a convergent sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset \text{ran}(M)$ to show that its limit is again in $\text{ran}(M)$. I already showed linearity, boundedness of $M$.

Comment: In general it would be a bit surprising if a random subspace like this was closed. Can you think of any elements of $L^2([0, \tfrac 12])$ not lying in the image of $M$? Then try to approximate one of these with functions from the range of $M$.

Comment: I thought about using $\textbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} = x \cdot \frac{1}{x} \cdot \textbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$. Where $\frac{1}{x}$ is not in $L^2$. But I can't seem to approximate the indicator function in the range of $M$.

Comment: Good idea! Note that you can approximate this indicator by indicator functions of the form $\mathbf 1_{[\varepsilon, \tfrac 12]}$ in $L^2$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$. Define a sequence:
$$f_n(x) = \frac{\chi_{[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2}]}}{x\sqrt{x+1}}$$

Observe that:
$$\int_{[0,1]} |\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}xf_n(x)-f(x)|^2 \ dx = \int_{[0,1]} \frac{|\chi_{[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2}]}-\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}|^2}{x+1} \ dx$$
Observe that $[0,\frac{1}{2}] = [0,\frac{1}{2n}] \cup [\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2}]$. Therefore:
$$\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}-\chi_{[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2}]} = \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2n}]} - \chi_{\{\frac{1}{2n}\}} $$

Using this, you can easily show that $\int_{[0,1]} |\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} xf_n(x)-f(x)|^2 \ dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. On the other hand, it is a relatively simple exercise to show that the function:
$$g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$x \mapsto g(x) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \ \text{if} \ x = 0\\
\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x+1}} & \ \text{if} \ x > 0
\end{cases}$$

is not square integrable. This is the function such that $mg = f$, up to almost everywhere equality. So, we've found a convergent sequence in $\text{ran}(M)$ such that the limit does not belong to $\text{ran}(M)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the operator $N:L^2(0,1/2)\to L^2(0,1/2)$ given by $(Nf)(x)=xf(x).$ The range of $N$ is closed if and only if the range of $M$ is closed. The operator $N$ is injective and its range is dense. The range is closed  if and only if the operator $N$ is invertible. But the inverse operator cannot be bounded as it acts by dividing by $x.$ Therefore the range of $N$ and consequently of $M$ is not closed.